# Issue when running Scrapy from a script in Celery: The installed reactor does not match the requested

Tags: scrapy, celery, twisted

There are many ways to start a scrapy spider from a script [(docs)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html). But when you deal with it in Celery it becomes somewhat complicated.

What I want to have is a function that will start scrapy **with the settings from the settings.py file**

My setup looks something like this:

```
import os
import traceback
from twisted.internet import reactor
from celery import shared_task
from billiard.context import Process
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from my_spider.spiders.spider import MySpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

@shared_task
def start_scrapy(link):
    run_spider(link)

def run_spider(link):
    def _crawl(spider, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            os.environ.setdefault("SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_spider.settings")
            settings = get_project_settings()
            settings.update(
                {
                    "FEEDS": {
                        f"output-{args[0]}.json": {
                            "format": "json",
                            "encoding": "utf-8",
                            "overwrite": True,
                        },
                    },
                }
            )
            runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
            deferred = runner.crawl(spider, *args, **kwargs) 
            deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
            reactor.run()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception: {e}")
            traceback.print_exc()

    process = Process(target=_crawl, args=(MySpider, link))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

Now, without the environ part it works, but it wouldn't have the settings from the settings.py file.

For some reason the error is silent, so I had to put prints with flush=True inside the scrapy source code. Thus I've found the following error: **`The installed reactor (twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor) does not match the requested one (twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor)`**

Of course in the spider settings I have

```
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
```

And with prints I have checked that the get_project_settings returns the desired settings.
I've tried out calling `asyncioreactor.install()` and only then importing the reactor, but to no avail.

I use macOS.

Celery configuration looks like this:
celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "listings.settings")

app = Celery("listings")

app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.conf.update(
    worker_concurrency=4,
    worker_prefetch_multiplier=1,
)
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

settings.py

```
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
REDIS_PORT = 6379

CELERY_BROKER_URL = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}"
CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 360
```

Package versions:

```
celery==5.3.6
Scrapy==2.11.1
Twisted==23.10.0
Django==4.2.4
```

Please help me find the solution to the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, with a clear mind I've come to a fairly logical solution: **remove the twisted reactor from settings** `settings.delete("TWISTED_REACTOR")`

Comment: You could just change `settings.py`. And it only makes sense if you don't need `AsyncioSelectorReactor`.

Comment: But this way I preserve the functionality of using scrapy just by calling from the command line "scrapy crawl". Both things do the same: delete AsyncioSelectorReactor. If you have a better solution, I'd love to learn from you.

Comment: I believe I've already described a better solution: remove the setting from `settings.py`. Not sure what do you "preserve" with your code.

Comment: I believe I've already described what I preserve with my code: when I run scrapy crawl my_crawler it will use AsyncioSelector

Comment: But it doesn't look like you need `AsyncioSelectorReactor` in which case it's easier to modify `settings.py`.